# Create an EdgeNGram analyzer supporting both sides in Azure Search

Tags: search, analyzer, azure-cognitive-search, elasticsearch-analyzers

When defining a custom analyzer for Azure Search there is an option of defining a token filter from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search) list.
I am trying to support search of both prefix and infix.
For example: if a field contains the name: 123 456, I want the searchable terms to contain:

```
1
12
123
23
3
4
45
456
56
6
```

When using the EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2 which seems to do the trick, there is an option of defining a "side" property, but only "front" and "back" are supported, not both.
the "front" (default) value generates this list:

```
1
12
123
4
45
456
```

and back generates:

```
123
23
3
456
56
6
```

I tried using two token two EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2s, but this creates terms from combining the two filters such as: "2" or "5":

```
1
12
123
23
3
4
45
456
56
6
2 // Unwanted
5 // Unwanted
```

I also tried using a "reverse" token, but this reverses everything and the results are still wrong.

I am using only one search field ("Name") and would prefer it to stay like this. (Thought of the option of using a different field named "name_reverse" with a different analyzer, but this is very inefficient and will cause a lot of headache when connecting the search engine to the data source.

For easier reference, this is the current index creation request:

```
{
 "name": "testindexboth",  
 "fields": [
  {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true },
  {"name": "Name", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "analyzer": "myAnalyzer"}
 ],
 "myAnalyzer": [
  {
   "name": "myAnalyzer",
   "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
   "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
    "tokenFilters":["front_filter", "back_filter"]
  }],

    "tokenFilters":[
            {
               "name":"front_filter",
               "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
               "maxGram":15,
               "side": "front"
            },
                        {
               "name":"back_filter",
               "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
               "maxGram":15,
               "side": "back"
            }
        ]
}
```

Is there an option of combining both, without getting them scramble up the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two fields to your index, with two different custom analyzers: one for prefix, one for suffix. When querying, query against both fields.

Comment: It will definitely work, but seems a bit like a hack, don't you think? It also forces me to use a field mapping function.

Comment: Perform a search on both fields, use the non-reversed one for fetch, no point in picking the reversed data, agreed, this is in-efficient. Detailed solution : https://github.com/mannu2050/Azure-Search-prefix-postfix-search/blob/master/Readme.md