# How to set the crawl rule in Azure Cognitive Search to index only the files starting with specific letters?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

How to set the crawl rule in Azure Cognitive Search to index only the files starting with specific letters (for example  files with Prefix Invoice_  etc) ? so that other files in the blob storage will not be crawled.

Swati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an EdgeNGram analyzer supporting both sides in Azure Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756336/create-an-edgengram-analyzer-supporting-both-sides-in-azure-search)

Comment: How about creating a folder in your blob container and store all files that you want to index in that folder?  If so , you can create a datasource with query param by the folder name directly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#step-1-create-a-data-source

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to this query , I got a reply for Azure search product team :The indexer only allows you to filter which files to be index based on their extension or based on the container they live in (documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage)...   so if you want to filter by a prefix the only way I can think of is to actually create a custom skill that takes the metadata_storage_path field and the content, and only output the content if the path/filename meets whatever pattern you are looking for. This takes a bit of effort (creating the [custom skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-interface)),  but it is doable.